# socket.io-client web socket connection failing in node.js child process

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using simple socket.io client module to connect to web socket but the connection is failing. The way I have learned is that right after you define socket, you can access connected property to find out the status of connection and it always return false. I am trying to connect to web socket in a child process on the same server where my main process is running.

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')("ws://xx.xx.xxx.xxx");
console.log(socket.connected);
```

Comment: `socket.io-client` isn't a Websocket client. Also, `socket.connected` will only be `true` after the `connect` event has fired.

Comment: I have already tried checking the connect event and it never fires.

Comment: Well, like I said: `socket.io-client` isn't a Websocket client, it's a SocketIO client and thus requires a SocketIO server to connect to.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I already have a server setup like so,var express  = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(6001);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

Comment: Try using `require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:6001')` (not `ws://...`) If that still doesn't work, try adding some error handlers. Also, how did you start the child process?

Comment: Thanks a lot that works like a charm!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150335/discussion-between-m-dagiya-and-robertklep).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SocketIO connections should be initiated over HTTP(S):

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:6001');
```

(instead of `ws://...`)

Then wait for the `connect` event; when that fires, the client is connected to the server;

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('connected to server!');
  ...
});
```